# Does a coordinate basis exist locally on any manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

A holonomic or coordinate basis for a differentiable manifold is a set of  basis vector fields $\{e_k\}$ such that some coordinate system $\{x_k\}$ exists such that $e_k=\partial/\partial x_k$.

A local condition for a basis to be holonomic is $[e_i,e_j]=0$. Can one always find a set of basis vector fields on a manifold which satisfy $[e_i,e_j]=0$ locally? Does this hold for all manifolds, including Lie groups?

Comment: Do you want this globally, or only in a neighborhood of each point?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Only in the neighborhood of each point, thank you.

Comment: A tangent space is just a vector space, and any vector space has a basis (assuming the axiom of choice, although this is unnecessary in the finite-dimensional case). I don't understand what you mean by "the basis vectors commute." It sounds like you're actually asking for a collection of vector fields, not a collection of tangent vectors. If so, you should clarify the wording.

Comment: By the definition of a manifold, you can introduce a coordinate system $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in a neighbourhood of any given point. And then $e_i=\partial/\partial x_i$ will be a coordinate basis, so if I understand your question correctly, the answer is trivially "yes"...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For a Lie group, if one uses the Lie algebra generators as the basis of the tangent space at the identity, then it would not be a coordinate basis since the Lie algebra generators don't commute. But according to Hans' and your comments in seems that there should exist a coordinate basis in the tangent space, whose elements do commute. This seems confusing, as only an abelian Lie group may have commuting generators.

Comment: @Meer: there is no Lie bracket on  *tangent vectors*. The Lie bracket is defined on *vector fields*. A basis for the Lie algebra of a Lie group is more than just a collection of bases for the tangent spaces of the Lie group: it's a collection of vector fields which, when evaluated at each point, form a basis of the tangent space at that point.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, thank you. I have edited the question as per your suggestion.  I believe Hans answer remains true?

Comment: @HansLundmark I have edited the question, I believe your answer remains true, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, to any local coordinate system there is associated a set of commuting vector fields $\partial/\partial x_k$.